# presenting a uiviewcontroller modally but with uinavigationcontroller stack

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have 3 view controllers A,B, and C. I present B modally from A. Then in B I want to dismiss (or unwind with storyboard) to viewcontroller C.

I have A and C belong together in the same UINavigationController stack, and A can push to C.

I  then want to be able to have B dismiss to C, but go back to A, not B. How can I achieve this using storyboard segues?

**Unwind Segue:**

I tried creating an unwind segue by writing the following method in C, and then dragging a UIBarButton action to the green exit icon in the storyboard editor and selecting it. Nothing is logged.

```
- (IBAction)unwindToViewMessage:(UIStoryboardSegue *)unwindSegue
{
    NSLog(@"unwound");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried creating an unwind segue from B to C?

Comment: @nhgrif yes and for some reason it won't execute...

Comment: If you've tried, you should include that detail in the question.  And include a detail explanation of exactly how the unwind segue is set up and exactly what happens when you try to execute it.

Comment: @nhgrif thanks, I've done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Unwind segues can allow transitioning only to existing instances of scenes in a storyboard.**
When you are trying to unwind to C from B, the `viewController` instance doesn't exist in the stack.

This is why, nothing gets logged from your 
`- (IBAction)unwindToViewMessage:(UIStoryboardSegue *)unwindSegue`
method.

An alternative option is to :

- Embed your `viewController` C in another `navigationController`.
- Add a custom `barButtonItem` called `Back`.
- Write another unwind method in your `viewController` A, called
  `(IBAction)unwindToVioewControllerA:(UIStoryboardSegue *)unwindSegue`.
- Set action of the custom `Back` button as the above mentioned unwind method.

Now your original unwind segue i.e.

```
- (IBAction)unwindToViewMessage:(UIStoryboardSegue *)unwindSegue
{
    NSLog(@"unwound");
}
```

would correctly unwind to `viewController` C, from where you can go to `viewController` A using the `Back` `barButton`.

the *storyBoard* will look something like this:
[image]

Hope this helps !